# Does Android Test Orchestrator generate any tests reports?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm intending to use [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator) into my test project and I've noticed that no reports are generated after a test suite completes its execution. Does orchestrator gather all test reports somewhere?

Comment: If you are to resolve this issue, please let me know how?

Comment: I'm using spoon. https://github.com/square/spoon

Answer (score 0):

Android Test Orchestrator generates an html report in `/build/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/*/*.html`

It also generates an XML report in `/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/flavors/*/TEST-{NameOfDevice}-{flavor}.xml`

If using a multi module project, the report is found within the module in which the tests were run and not the global builds folder.